# Prepopulate database with empty / null values [mysql]

Tags: mysql, database-design

What would be the best way to pre-populate a database with 100 empty fields and then begin the Auto_Increment?

What I mean to say, I want to reserve the first 100 userfields (ie UIDs which are auto_increment) 0 - 100 for "special users" and have the AUTO_INCREMENT start at 101 (as an example).

Obviously I can't set Auto_Increment to 101 as then it will start the UID at 101. And, I don't know beforehand how many special users there will be, however 100 sounds like a reasonable number to reserve.

What kind of null data can I insert and how would you go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes you can start an empty table's auto_increment from 101.

## SAMPLE CODE

```
use test
drop table if exists fizzydrink;
create table fizzydrink
(id int not null auto_increment,num1 int,num2 int,primary key (id));
show create table fizzydrink\G
alter table fizzydrink auto_increment = 101;
show create table fizzydrink\G
insert into fizzydrink (num1,num2) values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6);
select * from fizzydrink;
```

## SAMPLE CODE EXECUTED

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists fizzydrink;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> create table fizzydrink
    -> (id int not null auto_increment,num1 int,num2 int,primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> show create table fizzydrink\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: fizzydrink
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `fizzydrink` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table fizzydrink auto_increment = 101;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table fizzydrink\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: fizzydrink
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `fizzydrink` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into fizzydrink (num1,num2) values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from fizzydrink;
+-----+------+------+
| id  | num1 | num2 |
+-----+------+------+
| 101 |    1 |    2 |
| 102 |    3 |    4 |
| 103 |    5 |    6 |
+-----+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## CREATE 100 INITIAL USERS

```
use test
drop table if exists fizzydrink;
create table fizzydrink
(id int not null auto_increment,num1 int,num2 int,primary key (id));
show create table fizzydrink\G
insert into fizzydrink (id) values
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0);
select * from fizzydrink;
```

You cannot add user id `0` because the auto_increment interprets it as `GET NEXT ID`

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 1):

How about creating table with autoincrement option?

```
create table t ( 
  id int not null auto_increment, 
  v varchar(100), 
  primary key(id) ) 
auto_increment=101;

mysql> insert into t (v) values ("abc");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+-----+------+
| id  | v    |
+-----+------+
| 101 | abc  |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t values(1,"abc");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+-----+------+
| id  | v    |
+-----+------+
|   1 | abc  |
| 101 | abc  |
+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t (v) values ("abc");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+-----+------+
| id  | v    |
+-----+------+
|   1 | abc  |
| 101 | abc  |
| 102 | abc  |
+-----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I recommend strongly to avoid having id with some special meaning. Better to have a field that indicates that some row is special. I prefer an approach like the following:

```
create table t1 ( 
  id int not null auto_increment, 
  v varchar(100), 
  is_special bool default false, 
  primary key(id) 
);

mysql> insert into t1(v) values ("abc");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from t1;
+----+------+------------+
| id | v    | is_special |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | abc  |          0 |
+----+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just populate it with all `NULL` values except the fields which are declared as `NOT NULL`. For those `NOT NULL` fields you can use empty strings.

If it's just 100 rows you can do it with an `INSERT` statement or just add those rows manually with MySQL Workbench GUI.